# How can we create table without headers in Microsoft Excel Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-excel

I need to create a table in **Microsoft Excel** using **Graph API**.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/worksheet-post-tables?view=graph-rest-1.0

As per above document, if we set `hasHeaders` field as false in the create table API, it should create a table **without headers**. But still, I'm getting a table with headers. I added the screenshot below.
[image]

So how can create a table without headers in Excel?

Answer (score 2):

If I read the documentation correctly, even if your source does not have headers, Excel will create headers automatically:
[image]

After you create your table, you would need to `Update` the `WorkbookTable` object that you created, and set `ShowHeaders` to `False` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/table-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Thanks. Does `hasHeaders` have any specific thing to do? Seems it is a redundant field in the payload.

Comment: I am not sure, but my guess would be that it is required by the underlying Excel Online API that sits behind Microsoft Graph call.